# Focus-out event on clicking focused widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.1

I have the following behavior.
I overload `focusOutEvent()` handler for my widget class.  But the handler is called not only, when the widget losses focus, but either on clicking on it. Just like it would be losing focus and then regaining it.

**Question one:** Is it a bug?
**Question two:** If not, is there a reasonable way to handling focus losing? -- Slotting all `focusChange()` signals does not look attractive.

I'm using Qt5.1

Comment: What's your widget's focus policy?

Comment: I tried `Strong` and `Click`.

Comment: Do you have one or many instances of this widget, when one gains focus others looses it. 
Platform? Sample Code? Other details?

Answer (score 0):

Name your widgets.

```
myWidget->setObjectName("MyWidget 1");

myWidget2->setObjectName("MyWidget 2");
```

Then at the top of your `focusOutEvent()` and your `focusInEvent()`, put a helpful but of debugging code:

```
qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "called by" << qPrintable(this->objectName());
```

Now you can see what is causing your issue.

You may also want to dump your object tree, so you can see if you have multiple instances floating around.

```
QObject::dumpObjectTree();
```

But call it from your `QMainWindow` or whatever window is your outermost window.

Hope that helps.